# Where Ram Stuti is located in Ramcharitmanas?

Tags: rama, stotra, ramcharitmanas

Where is the Ram Stuti 
"**Bhaye Prakat Kripala Deēen........**"
located In Ramcharitmanas?
Actually, I bought a Ramcharitmanas and I was searching for the Stuti but didn't get it yet. Can Anyone Help me in finding out where it is situated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Shri Ram Stuti you are looking for is present in Balakanda of  Ramcharita Manas  1.191  in Chanda (छन्द ) section.

Below are the  the entire shlokas

भए प्रगट कृपाला दीनदयाला कौसल्या हितकारी। 
हरषित महतारी मुनि मन हारी अद्भुत रूप बिचारी।। 
लोचन अभिरामा तनु घनस्यामा निज आयुध भुज चारी। 
भूषन बनमाला नयन बिसाला सोभासिंधु खरारी।। 
कह दुइ कर जोरी अस्तुति तोरी केहि बिधि करौं अनंता। 
माया गुन ग्यानातीत अमाना बेद पुरान भनंता।। 
करुना सुख सागर सब गुन आगर जेहि गावहिं श्रुति संता। 
सो मम हित लागी जन अनुरागी भयउ प्रगट श्रीकंता।। 
ब्रह्मांड निकाया निर्मित माया रोम रोम प्रति बेद कहै। 
मम उर सो बासी यह उपहासी सुनत धीर पति थिर न रहै।। 
उपजा जब ग्याना प्रभु मुसकाना चरित बहुत बिधि कीन्ह चहै। 
कहि कथा सुहाई मातु बुझाई जेहि प्रकार सुत प्रेम लहै।। 
माता पुनि बोली सो मति डौली तजहु तात यह रूपा। 
कीजै सिसुलीला अति प्रियसीला यह सुख परम अनूपा।। 
सुनि बचन सुजाना रोदन ठाना होइ बालक सुरभूपा। 
यह चरित जे गावहिं हरिपद पावहिं ते न परहिं भवकूपा।।

---

Here are the verses with English translation by [**Gita Press**](https://archive.org/details/RamcharitmanasGitapressEnglish/page/n205)

---

and here is another one by 
Bhavartha Bodhini - Shree Ram Charit Manas -   By [**International  Ram Charit Manas  Research center .**](https://archive.org/details/BhavarthaBodhini/page/n207)

Comment: Also track the stuti in IIT Kanpur Ramcharitamanasa  portal . Just type the number 192 in the box - https://www.ramcharitmanas.iitk.ac.in/ramcharitmanas\

Comment: Thank you ♪┌|∵|┘♪ O_o(✷‿✷)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar IITK Ramcharitmanas  portal's exact verse direct link would be like https://www.ramcharitmanas.iitk.ac.in/ramcharitmanas?page=0%2C191 you can copy the link from next/predv button... :)